# Bluetooth Low Energy GATT Explorer for Windows?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

On macOS, we've got LightBlue, among others. Are there any solutions for Windows which allow us to debug / reverse engineer / explorer GATT Profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two options that I've used in the past :

- [Nordic Semiconductor Master Control Panel for PC](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF51-DK)
  (You will need an nRF51 development kit or USB dongle to use this). The application can be found under the Downloads -> PC software section in the link I listed above.
- Use the Silicon Labs (Bluegiga) BLED112 dongle along with the BLEGUI application included with the SDK which is available to download at [Silicon Labs' BLED112 website](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/bluetooth/bluetooth-smart-modules/Pages/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle.aspx).

Both of these Windows applications will allow you to discover BLE peripherals and connect and query their GATT.